# Import Camelot - ImportError: DLL load failed while importing cv2

Tags: python, opencv, python-camelot

I am an absolute beginner in coding in Python. My aim is to use the `camelot` library to read tables from `pdf`'s, and store it in an Excel spreadsheet. I used: `conda install -c conda-forge camelot-py` to `install camelot` in VS Code.

Anybody can help? I have also installed OpenCV, but the problem persists.

The error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\je0437a\Documents\SEB Work Sheet\Invoice Scanner\UntukDimain.py", line 1, in <module>
    import camelot
  File "C:\Users\je0437a\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\jialoong\lib\site-packages\camelot\__init__.py", line 6, 
in <module>
    from .io import read_pdf
  File "C:\Users\je0437a\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\jialoong\lib\site-packages\camelot\io.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .handlers import PDFHandler
  File "C:\Users\je0437a\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\jialoong\lib\site-packages\camelot\handlers.py", line 9, 
in <module>
    from .parsers import Stream, Lattice
  File "C:\Users\je0437a\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\jialoong\lib\site-packages\camelot\parsers\__init__.py", 
line 4, in <module>
    from .lattice import Lattice
  File "C:\Users\je0437a\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\jialoong\lib\site-packages\camelot\parsers\lattice.py", line 25, in <module>
    from ..image_processing import (
  File "C:\Users\je0437a\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\jialoong\lib\site-packages\camelot\image_processing.py", 
line 3, in <module>
    import cv2
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing cv2: The specified module could not be found.
```

I tried to run a short code to test whether I had the library installed and an error came out. I isolated the code, and left only 'import camelot' and that was the source of the error.